# how to store a downloaded image to sdcard in android

Tags: android, image

i have the following code which works fine to download image form url . 
i want to save the image loaded in the imageview to sdcard on a button click.
can anyone please help me how can i save the downloaded image to sdcard.

```
public class DownloadimageActivity extends Activity {
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    }  
    public void downloadPicture(View view) {  
     final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Snapshot",  
             "retriving image..");  
     dialog.show();  
     new Thread(new Runnable() {  
         @Override  
         public void run() {  
             try {  
                 final Bitmap downloadBitma = downloadBitmap("http://42.60.144.184:8081/snapshot.cgi?&user=admin&pwd=admin&resolution=8");  
                 final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                     @Override  
                     public void run() {  
                         imageView.setImageBitmap(downloadBitma);  

                     }  
                 });  

             } catch (IOException e) {  
                 e.printStackTrace();  
             } finally {  
                 dialog.dismiss();  
             }  
         }  
     }).start();  

 }  

 private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) throws IOException {  
     HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url.toString());  
     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);  

     StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();  
     int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();  
     if (statusCode == 200) {  
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  
         byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);  

         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0,  
                 bytes.length);  

         return bitmap;  
     } else {  
         throw new IOException("Retrive failed, HTTP response code "  
                 + statusCode + " - " + statusLine.getReasonPhrase());  
     }

 }
 }
```

i tried with the following code but it doesnt work.

```
     ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     downloadBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
     //you can create a new file name "test.jpg" in sdcard folder.
     File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                             + File.separator + "test.jpg");
     f.createNewFile();
     //write the bytes in file
     FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
     fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What fails? Does it throw an exception? Also, have you requested permissions to write to external storage?

Comment: in eclipse it asks to create a new variable downloadBitmap

Comment: Does Eclipse ask that for a certain line in your code above?

Comment: in which place should i place the code to store image in the activity program ?

Comment: @Thunder Rabbit yes it asks to create a new variable downloadBitmap as quickfix suggession

Comment: on what line does it ask this?

Comment: it asks in this line

downloadBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

Comment: @radish: Read my last comment on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Bitmap downloadBitma = downloadBitmap(...);
```

Your Bitmap name is missing the 'p' at the end so this won't work...

```
downloadBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
```

Oh, and don't give a variable the same name as a method - I don't even know if that is legal in Java.

Comment: I thought this at first, but he used `downloadBitma` later in the code.

Comment: downloadBitma is a variable, and the code works fine to and it could download and display image in the imageview. now i want to save the image that is displayed in the imageview

Comment: Well change the line where you are compressing it to `downloadBitma.compress(...)` - that's what I'm trying to show you in the answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i placed the code after the new thread() function and it worked fine after that...